# How to inject mocks into a method two steps down from the tested class

Tags: java, spring, mockito

I want to write a kind of an integration test of a class and the "lower" classes that it calls during operation. I want to mock the database connection that is called by the "lower" class, but I have not found a way to do this.

I have a class, that calls another class, that calls the database through jdbcTemplate. I want to inject a mock jdbcTemplate to the lower class, but I seem to be injecting it to a wrong instance of the class. The code follows this template:

```
@Component
public class A {

    @AutoWired
    B b

    public String someMethod() {
        b.otherMethod();
    }

}


@Component
public class B {

    @AutoWired
    jdbcTemplate jdbctemplate

    public String otherMethod() {
        jdbctemplate.query(args);
    }

}
```

The test is like follows:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.Silent.class)
public class aTestClass { 

    @Mock
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @InjectMocks
    B b;

    @InjectMocks
    A a;

    @Test
    public void aTest() {
        a.someMethod();
    }
}
```

But when I run this test I get a NullPointerException at a.someMethod() - it seems that the B-object being called is null.

The problem is, that if I mock B, then it's not ever going to actually call jdbcTemplate since it is a mock.

Can anybody shed some light on how I could inject a mock jdbcTemplate to a B-object that is being called by A?

Answer (score 3):

**If you want an actual integration test:**

**1)** Don't mock the template.. mock the entire repository.

**2)** You don't need `@InjectMocks` in an integration test. Spring does the DI.

**3)** As this is IT test you would need to use `SpringRunner.class`, not the `MockitoJUnitRunner.class` runner.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class aTestClass { 

    @MockBean
    B b;

    @Autowired
    A a;

    @Test
    public void aTest() {
        a.someMethod();
    }
}
```

**For a unit test** just mock the B and inject on A:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.Silent.class)
public class aTestClass { 

    @Mock
    B b;

    @InjectMocks
    A a;

    @Test
    public void aTest() {
        a.someMethod();
    }
}
```

Do not mock dependencies of dependencies in a unit test. You should not care about lower levels there.

Comment: Thank you for the help. This causes a NoSuchBeanDefinitionException with A - do I need to do a @ComponentScan or something like that?

Comment: Also a second question: I want to specify what JdbcTemplate returns when queried, so do I also add this:

    @MockBean
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

Answer (score 0):

After DuckDuckGoing a bit I managed to get the test working with Maciejs instruction. At first it did not work, but adding @Configuration to both the beans it did. Here is the code that worked for me:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class aTestClass { 

    @MockBean
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Autowired
    B b;

    @Autowired
    A a;

    @Test
    public void aTest() {
        when(jdbcTemplate.query(args)).thenAnswer(whatyouwant));
        a.someMethod();
    }

    @Configuration
    @Import(A.class)
    static class AConfig {
    }

    @Configuration
    @Import(B.class)
    static class BConfig {
    }

}
```